# formatted bibliography: want URL to be placed before, not after, year

Tags: bibliographies

I'm a newbie to bibliography styles in Latex, 
I'm trying to print out a bibliography, which should look this

> title, url, year

Right now, though, it looks like

> title, year, url

My bib file looks like this:

```
@article{gleichtaktdrossel,
  title={{Funktionsweise einer Gleichtaktdrossel}},
  note = {URL: \url{http://www.richtek.com/~/media/Richtek/Design%20Support/Technical%20Documentation/AN008/EN/Version6/image002.gif?file=preview.png}},
  year={2008},
}
```

If I don't mention a url in the bib file the year is printed out at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Would you mind posting a full compilable code?

Comment: Assuming you're using BibTeX, the formatting of bibliographic entries is determined by the chosen bibliography style. Which bibliography style does your document employ?

Comment: Are you really using the entry type `@article` for the entry at hand? You must be getting warnings about missing fields, right? Have you considered using the entry type `@misc` instead?

Comment: Im using texmaker and there im including the bib files. I don't get any warning about missing fields :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making two mistakes. Nothing calamitous, for sure, just ordinary rookie mistakes which can happen while generating formatted bibliographies.

- You should *not* be using the entry type `@article` for the entry at hand. The `@article` type is meant for pieces that were published in journals. You have probably been getting warning messages from BibTeX -- which you may or may not have been ignoring, that some entries were missing required fields. For the `@article` type, fields named `author` and `journal` are required. You should probably be using the `@misc` entry type instead for the entry at hand.
- Once you've switched to the `@misc` entry type, you should also change the name of the field that contains the URL from `note` to `howpublished`: In most bibliography styles I'm familiar with, the material in the `year` field is placed *after* the material contained in the `howpublished` field. (As you've discovered, material in a field named `note` tends to be placed at the very end.)

The following example uses the `plainnat` bibliography style and the `natbib` citation management package. The ordering of the fields -- `title` before `howpublished` before `year` -- is the same in many other bibliography styles.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{gleichtaktdrossel,
  title={{Funktionsweise einer Gleichtaktdrossel}},
  howpublished = {URL: \url{http://www.richtek.com/%7E/media/Richtek/Design%20Support/Technical%20Documentation/AN008/EN/Version6/image002.gif?file=preview.png}},
  year={2008},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{gleichtaktdrossel}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```